# Vue promise error, I am having error with promise

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs3

While the same method works just fine with another api call, fetch from this api is getting me error on promise. the error reads
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')`

My fetch code reads as below:

```
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
async setup() {
    const prompProducts = ref(null);
    const bc_prompProducts = await fetch(
      "https://booking.hemantbhutanrealestate.com/api/v1/get_frontend_products"
    );
    prompProducts.value = await bc_prompProducts.json();
return {
      prompProducts,
   };
  },
};
```

While this same method works without error on my other api calls, am getting error on this one. Please help, the site is on production already!

Comment: Can you please share more error logs. I could even make fetch request in my browser inspect window.

Comment: as it is, the code should work fine - in the error trace, does it show `prompProducts.value = await bc_prompProducts.json();` as the source of the error?

Comment: https://snipboard.io/CWEXN9.jpg
this is it, no more logs, nothing, except for this as error log!

Comment: sorry again, i posted wrong snapshot, that was not for this error...

Comment: well @UjwalPradhan - how about you post the right image for this error - because the code in the image you posted (and removed) https://snipboard.io/3y0t2a.jpg would definitely result in the error you are getting - and since your `setup` is `async`, you are using `suspense` when using this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your async call in function and call it, or you can use `onMounted` hook:

```js
const { ref, onMounted } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const prompProducts = ref([]);
    onMounted(async() => {
      const bc_prompProducts = await fetch(
      "https://booking.hemantbhutanrealestate.com/api/v1/get_frontend_products"
      )
      prompProducts.value = await bc_prompProducts.json()
    })
    return { prompProducts }
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="pro in prompProducts" :key="pro.id">
    <p>{{ pro }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Bravo hey mate, you are right, but it works this way, cheers :)

Comment: yea, I know it does work - somehow I think asynchronous components + suspense is beyond OP anyway :p